# Unknown issue with getter/setter acess; Error Message is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at Object.addDishToCourse"

Tags: javascript, setter, getter

The issue is there is an unknown error in a small code.  The method/function to get a set of courses which are properties of courses property. The are arrays of dinner items for a meal.  It's gotta be a small syntax error but I can't for the life of me find the dang thing.  Thought I would throw it out there and see if someone can find the little bug. :)

I have examined the code, when through line by line for typos or variable name type misspellings etc in notepad++ and done some google searching, asking on CodeAcademy forums and review the coursematerial to see if there is some item I am missing.  I have tested setting the properties to not be private variables but am still seeing the error message.  It's gotta be something simple that someone more experienced will see right off of hand.  The code is basically nearly identical to the solution video.  So I have basically just reduced my solution to the videos but still get this error message.

The error is TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Object.addDishToCourse

```
const menu = {

  //Our restaurants great select of food
  _courses: {
    appetizers: [],
    mains: [],
    desserts: [],
},

//warm up the appetite!!!!!
get appetizers(){
 return this._courses.appetizers; 
},

set appetizers(appetizers){
    this._courses.appetizers = appetizers;
 },

//The main course baby!!!!
get mains(){
 return this._courses.mains;  
},

set mains(mains){
   this._courses.mains = mains;
 },

//Save room for dessert!!!!!
get desserts(){
 return this._courses.desserts; 
},

 set desserts(desserts){
   this._courses.desserts = desserts;
 },

//Get Method to access the list of great appetizers, main dishes, and desserts to choose from :)
get courses() {
      return {
         appetizers: this._courses.appetizers,
         mains: this._courses.mains,
         desserts: this._courses.desserts
   };
},

  /*  error was here ????
get courses() {
      return {
         appetizers: this.appetizers,
         mains: this.mains,
         desserts: this.desserts
   };
}, */ 

// Sets a dish to a course object. What fun is it to have more selections  on the menu!!
addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice){
    const dish = {
      name: dishName,
      price: dishPrice,
    };
  //doesn't work at this point
     this._courses[courseName].push(dish)
   },   

//Generates a random dish from a course's list of exciting options
getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName){
    const dishes = this._courses[courseName];
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random()*dishes.length);
    return dishes [index];  
}, 

//Creates an random meal and generates a price of the said meal
generateRandomMeal(){
    const appetizer =this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
    const main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
    const dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
    const totalprice = appetizer[price]+main[price]+dessert[price];
    return console.log(`Your appetizer is ${appetizer.name}, your main dish is ${main.name}, and your dessert is ${dessert.name}. The total price of your meal is ${totalprice}.`);
  }, 
};

//What's our menu going to be. Let's add some selections.
menu.addDishToCourse('mains','pizza',2.00);
console.log(menu.addDishToCourse('mains','pizza',2.00));
menu.addDishToCourse('mains','salmon',4.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains','burger',1.50);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers','salad',1.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers','snails',1.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers','mushroom soup',1.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('dessert','fruit salad',0.50);
menu.addDishToCourse('dessert','orange serbert',2.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('dessert','vanilla ice cream',3.00);

const meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();
console.log(meal);
```

Comment: In the initialization, it's "desserts", but when you call that function you're passing different names. The code does not verify that the passed course name is correct. Also, in `getRandomDishFromCourse` you misspelled "length".

Comment: If you've fixed the code, you should update the question. The code still has all the same problems.

Comment: Done, seeing anything on the _courses: properties section & addDishToCourse section that would cause the .push method to fail.

Comment: You've still got basically the same problem: in the initialization, it's "desserts", but when you call `addDishToCourse()` you use "dessert".